# How to get time value of MAX(speed) in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select, relational-database

I have a table with the following structure:

```
Id | Speed | Time
```

I want to get the time of the row that contains the maximum speed.

My example query doesn't return the correct record.

```
SELECT MAX(speed), time FROM info WHERE id = 1 AND time > 1234
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could order the result and take the first record:

```
SELECT   speed, time
FROM     info 
WHERE    id = 1 AND time > 1234
ORDER BY speed DESC
LIMIT    1
```

Comment: Omg, how did I not remember this solution xD. Thank you!

Comment: Not especially efficient as it has to assemble the query, order it, and return the first row.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT MAX(speed) as speed, time FROM info WHERE id = 1 AND time > 1234 ORDER BY id
```

Probably you try to get the column bad in the fetch. So try giving an alias an using it as the column name.

Or try it as getting max as a condition value in a subquery:

```
SELECT * FROM info WHERE id = 1 AND speed = (SELECT MAX(speed) FROM info) AND time>1234;
```

Comment: Does this "as" make the difference?

Comment: @Engo Where did you check the result of the query?

Comment: @Engo I usually use max I don't know why its result was wrong I want to see the query result

Comment: @Engo Trying `GROUP BY id` in the end of the query

Comment: @Mureinik any idea why this happens?

Comment: @Engo I edit my answer try with the second option. Sometimes doing a subquery works good because of the rest of the conditions there will be apart

Answer (score 0):

```
select id, speed, time
  from info
 where speed = (select max(speed)
                  from info);
```